# SQLAlchemy merge() not working using flask

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, flask, crud

I am learning how to use sqlalchemy and I am developing small app. I am having some issues trying to update data stored in the db using the ORM. I'm not sure what I am missing. The form `edit_product.html` gets populated with the right data however the `return redirect(url_for` statement is fired without updating the data. I am using merge(), I tried using `add()` as suggested by some tutorials, however if I do this I get an error saying that the record already exists.

This is my `edit_product` function in the `views.py`:

```
from database import db_session
@app.route('/product/edit/<int:product_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_product(product_id):
    product = Product.query.filter(Product.id == product_id).first()
    form = NewOtrosForm(obj=product)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request.form
        if form.validate():
            form.populate_obj(product)
            db_session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('product'))
    else:
        return render_template('edit_product.html', form=form)
```

This is what I have in my edit form in the jinja2 template:

```
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
    <form method=post action="">
        <dl>
            {{ render_field(form.name) }}
            {{ render_field(form.price) }}
            {{ render_field(form.description) }}
            {{ render_field(form.provider) }}
            {{ render_field(form.detalles) }}
        </dl>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Save Changes"></p>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to change the below from :

```
form = NewOtrosForm(obj=product)
```

to:

```
form = NewOtrosForm(request.form, obj=product)
```

Comment: Thanks @codegeek - I tried using your suggestion but it returns `AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'POST'`.

Comment: Are you using WTForms or Flask-WTForms ?

Comment: I am using wtforms. By using the `request.form` it was fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use use [`merge()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#merging) here, its purpose is to transfer state from an outside object into a new or already existing instance within a session. Your `product` object already belongs to the session, so it's enough to call `form.populate_obj(product)` (changes to `product` marks it as "dirty" in this session) and `db_session.commit()` after that.

Comment: Thanks for your response Audrius – I have implemented your suggestion but still the updates are not being processed. I have updated the code reflecting the changes I made as per your suggestion. Could this be a problem with models class itself? I am using inheritance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could be that `product` isn't modified, so `commit()` sees no changes and does nothing. Try checking `db_session.dirty` after `form.populate_obj(product)`, it should contain `product` if it indeed was modified.

Comment: I tried `dirty` but nothing happened either. I have also tried calling the subclass which is called `Otros` but it doesn't work either. Do you have any suggestion on why the `product` isn't being modified?

Comment: My guess is that your `form` doesn't get the data from `POST` request, and since you've given it values from `product` (`NewOtrosForm(obj=product)`), that same data is being validated and given back to `product`. Because it's the same data, `db_session` sees no changes and does not emit `UPDATE` on `commit()`.